# Making a class template declared in an outer anonymous namespace a friend

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend

Clang refuses to compile the following code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzGakAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwczGwKiUwrANQ7APT7OwDyAG7RYrQ7hgIAniyLCjvrmJvbmDt4T8SYAI5eeB%2B6GuDGBogYDFQBB2UR2Pwe53QADoTBoAIImADsVnRqLRBEwLESBgJOxMsTcBFuiUYrA%2BABVydg8UNiF4HDsAGLEPCuck4jHol5vXYMBR4rECvHIAwKJ5CTDIH4ECXYvF7PYEokkj7kynU2lsHaM2LM9EanZUHmuHas9nQ7m80H8i0HI4QLizCXmjUTRzIHanVB4YH8VAQWZktWYgAiqrjsSluNjbuedJFHzF3vxhOJTFJeqpNJexqZLIIbI5jr5yYFFqDIZh9Qj6o1ktbrueChAIAVSswBB7YZbiY1hx2EDMXp9nfH2GIxBI12htGCH0nsxAHdd47AHDDe8%2BTyYO0SPNO%2BY%2BbBK0R2qCoOz3EBuDHujzTGy2K03IDFPb7yp7tuWJxsmCZJhiKbji%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%2BXxYk6U8RwmGM6ZQnHKFAvQveOyS6D4OQ3LMOK4jqB47eWPE%2BJtHk6QjGsVTNMcZbDNM4JnCs%2BzEnfRwZi/cz8dB2T8znIZ6QgJIQA%3D)) while gcc sees no problem with it. Clang error message is shown below line marked (2):

```
namespace  // Overall anonymous namespace is required and cannot be removed.
{

template <typename T>
struct Friend;

namespace ns
{

class Secret
{
    template <typename T>
    friend struct Friend;     // (1)

    static void foo() {}
};

} // namespace ns

template <typename T>
struct Friend
{
    void bar()
    {
        ns::Secret::foo();   // (2)
        // Error at line (2):
        // 'foo' is a private member of '(anonymous namespace)::ns::Secret'
    }
};

} // anonymous namespace
```

The reason, I assume, is that line (1) is treated as a declaration of a new class template `struct ns::Friend<T>` rather than a reference to `::(anonymous namespace)::Friend<T>`.

The questions are:

1. Who's right -- clang or gcc?
2. If clang is right, then is there a way to make it understand that line (1) doesn't introduce new class template, but refers to existing one?

Comment: Note: [gcc will also reject this code](https://godbolt.org/z/nP7EE1hhG) (for the same reason) if you try to instantiate `Friend<T>::bar()` for any type `T`.

Comment: GCC just discards template part completely because it's not used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right that simply `friend struct Friend` is a declaration of a templated class `::(anonymous namespace)::ns::Friend`. Both compilers are right, as when you attempt to use `Friend<T>::bar()` gcc will complain about access as well (clang just checks a lot earlier than gcc)

To specify the class template in the global namespace, you must write that out:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    friend struct ::Friend;     // (1)
```

This works for GCC, but clang seems broken and doesn't find `Friend` in the global namespace.

These two workarounds seem to work:

```cpp
// Make the entire unnamed namespace an inline namespace
inline namespace
{
// ...
}


// Add an explicit using directive to help clang find Friend in `::`
namespace {

template<typename T>
struct Friend;

}
using ::Friend;
namespace {
namespace ns {
// ...
}
}
```

Comment: To be clear, GCC is interpreting the `::` case correctly; this qualified lookup should follow the (implicit) *using-directive* for the unnamed namespace.